# Exporting multiple TAR's to maintain file structure and names

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I've been struggling with this one for a couple days now, as I'm not very code-savvy. Basically, I was given a giant zip file full of reports that someone needs access to. When that's extracted, it has a full directory structure, and all the files are .tar.gz files. I've got a working batch file to extract all .tar.gz to .tar, and then delete the .gz's.

The problem I'm facing now is that inside the TAR's, all the file names are meaningless as a series of numbers. I'm trying to make a .bat that will extract the TAR's and rename the contents to the same file name as the .tar had. (There is only one file per TAR).

Here's what I've got at the moment:

```
FOR /D /r %%F in ("*") DO (
    pushd %CD%
    cd %%F
    SET 
    FOR %%X in (*.tar) DO (
        set filename="%%X"
        "C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe" x "%%X" -aou -o"%%F\temp\"
        REN "%%F\temp\*" %filename%
        REN "%%F\temp\*.tar" "*.null"
        MOVE "%%F\temp\*.null" "%%F"
        RMDIR "%%F\Temp\"
        DEL "%%X"
    )
popd
)
```

I've tried loading %%F into variables, but that caused another set of problems. I have a final script that uses TrID to identify and correct file types, so the .null value is just temporary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this - it is meant to extract the TAR file, rename the extracted file to the same name as the TAR with .null on the end, and then delete the original TAR file and move the renamed file to where the original TAR file was, removing the temp folder.

It's meant to be run in the main folder with all the TAR files in folders beneath it.  Copy some to another folder and try it.

```
@echo off
FOR /r %%F in (*.tar) DO (
        "C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe" x "%%F" -aou -o"%%~dpF\temp\"
        REN "%%~dpF\temp\*.*" "%%~nF.null"
        DEL "%%F"
        MOVE "%%~dpF\temp\%%~nF.null" "%%~dpF"
        RMDIR "%%~dpF\temp\"
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Foxidrive, that works a treat! You are amazing!